# How to use @SecondaryTable with CrudRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `SecondaryTable` to map bean schema to multiple tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address1")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="address2")
})
```

How an I then tell spring to create a `Repository` that uses the values from table `address2`?

```
interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
    //this one uses address1
}
```

I then want to be able to query only the **secondary table** by the `CrudRepository`. But how can I explicit tell spring to query the `address2` table using the `AddressRepository` above?

(think of address2-table as a kind of archive table. Only if the address is not found in the primary address1-table, then address2 should be queried).

Comment: The whole point of `@SecondaryTable` is to hide the fact that an entity is mapped to  > 1 table. If you want to work with Address independently then don't use `@SecondaryTable` and map it as a `@OneToOne`.

Comment: So, but how can I then decide of which table the data is fetched from by using a `CrudRepository`? Or will it join all the secondary tables before?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve and, given your profile, find the question surprising somewhat surprising.

Comment: I have a similar situation to @membersound, there are many reason why you may want to store instances of the same data in two different tables that have the same columns. One example is if you want to store old data, or less frequently needed data. Suppose in a stock market prices scenario, I'm interested mostly in today's prices and maybe yesterdays, and then the end of months prices, I would like to move everything else to another table for speed, how can I have a repository distinguish between the two?

Comment: Secondary table is NOT for handling "active vs archived" scenario. What DBMS you are using? If performance is the reason you split a table into two, you may use other way to solve, like partitioning. Another way is, though I won't recommend, to map `ActiveAddress` and `ArchivedAddress` as some kind of inheritance hierarchy, and make use of `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy

Comment: I'm using `postgres` 9.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can represent two tables which are store different but related data in one entity by using SecondaryTable like user and user_address tables. What You are trying is storing same data in two different tables whhich are identically same. Therefore, SecondaryTable doesn't fit your needs. You should use inheritance annotation with strategy table per class. Here is an example;

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AddressBase {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name='address1')
public class Address1 extends AddressBase {}

@Entity
@Table(name='address2')
public class Address2 extends AddressBase {}
```

Then, you can write repository for each entity and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding what `@SecondaryTable` is for. It is a way to split a single entity among different database tables.

From the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html)

> Specifies a secondary table for the annotated entity class. Specifying
>   one or more secondary tables indicates that the data for the entity
>   class is stored across multiple tables. If no SecondaryTable
>   annotation is specified, it is assumed that all persistent fields or
>   properties of the entity are mapped to the primary table. If no
>   primary key join columns are specified, the join columns are assumed
>   to reference the primary key columns of the primary table, and have
>   the same names and types as the referenced primary key columns of the
>   primary table.

Your annotations, in their current state, say that there exists an `Address` entity, with data in the `address1` and `address2` table, which can be combined by joining on the primary key of the `address1` table.

I think for what you want to do, and have it work without overriding your `CrudRepository`, is to just use different tables. You will need to query both tables anyway if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I want to create some kind of "active" and "archived" table. Both of course must have the same data structure, thus have the same `Address` Entity. When using `CrudRepository`, I have to find a way to tell spring which table to select for the query. But how can I by default query `address1`, and at will redirect it eg to `address2` table explicit?

Comment: @membersound: Look at nsylmz's answer. Create a repository for each address class, then write a custom controller which performs your logic. I can't find anything that exists where you can just configure the behavior you want. Seems like a fairly common use case, so perhaps a feature request for the spring-data team.