# Spring JPA Specify entity's table name on the repository interface

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I want to create multiple repositories for the same entity class. 
The first and simplest scenario I want to save some of the instances of my class as rows in a different table than the primary table (which is designated on the entity itself). 
other scenarios would be to create remote back ups hence the whole datasource would be different. 
Does Spring allow things like that?

Comment: I wrote an answer for a similar question (except it was for spring-data-mongo):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337453/customizing-spring-data-repository-bean-names-for-use-with-multiple-data-sources

Comment: did the link help ? Are you still looking for an answer ?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet - I was fixing a few other issues in my system. I'll try to get down to it this evening. thanks

Comment: Hi @Alex sorry it took me a while to get round to this. The link you reference is about referencing a different database (MongoDB specific) but everything else is the same. My issue is more around the same database, but I need to reference a different table. I can't see how I can specify a tablename in the repository.! so essentially, same class instances can reside in two different tables.

Comment: @Alex I found this that may be a solution SecondaryTables

Comment: After your last comments, I looked around and found SecondaryTables too. I tested it and it does not seem to be taken into account by the Spring Data Repositories...

Comment: I've posted an answer

Comment: Ss for the SecondaryTables with Repository, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439814/how-to-use-secondarytable-with-crudrepository/41378453#41378453

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll want this, but here it is anyway... The best I could find using Spring Data Repositories is the following:

**(1a) Manually define 2 repository beans to use 2 datasources:**

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("db1")
public ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb1() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelJpaRepository, Model, String> myFactory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelJpaRepository, Model, String>();
    myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(ModelJpaRepository.class);
    myFactory.setEntityManager(entityManagerFactory1().createEntityManager());
    myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("db2")
public ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb2() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelJpaRepository, Model, String> myFactory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelJpaRepository, Model, String>();
    myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(ModelJpaRepository.class);
    myFactory.setEntityManager(entityManagerFactory2().createEntityManager());
    myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myFactory.getObject();
}
```

**(1b): Define the 2 datasources (referred to by the previous repository definitions):**

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
    bds.setDriverClassName(...);
    bds.setUrl(...);
    bds.setUsername(...);
    bds.setPassword(...);
    return bds;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
    bds.setDriverClassName(...);
    bds.setUrl(...);
    bds.setUsername(...);
    bds.setPassword(...);
    return bds;
}
```

**(1c): Define 2 entityManagers - 1 per datasource (referred to by the previous repository definitions):**

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory1() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource1());
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("pu1");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return entityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory2() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource2());
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("pu2");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return entityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
}
```

**(2) Inject the 2 repositories and use them:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("db1")
private ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("db2")
private ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb2;

...

modelJpaRepositoryDb1.save(model);
modelJpaRepositoryDb2.save(model);
```

**(3) Define the "OtherModel" and include the "Model" as embedded:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OTHER_TABLE")
public class OtherTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    private Model model;

    public OtherTable(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.id = model.getId();
    }
}
```

For info, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41378453/641627) suggests using `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, to achieve define an additional model (inheritance vs composition).

**(4) Define the 2 repositories for the OtherTable:**

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("db1")
public OtherTableJpaRepository otherTableJpaRepositoryDb1() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<OtherTableJpaRepository, OtherTable, String> myFactory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<OtherTableJpaRepository, OtherTable, String>();
    myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(OtherTableJpaRepository.class);
    myFactory.setEntityManager(entityManagerFactory1().createEntityManager());
    myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("db2")
public OtherTableJpaRepository otherTableJpaRepositoryDb2() {
    JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<OtherTableJpaRepository, OtherTable, String> myFactory = new JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<OtherTableJpaRepository, OtherTable, String>();
    myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(OtherTableJpaRepository.class);
    myFactory.setEntityManager(entityManagerFactory2().createEntityManager());
    myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myFactory.getObject();
}
```

**(5) Inject and use them all:**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("db1")
private ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("db2")
private ModelJpaRepository modelJpaRepositoryDb2;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("db1")
private OtherTableJpaRepository otherTableJpaRepositoryDb1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("db2")
private OtherTableJpaRepository otherTableJpaRepositoryDb2;

// ...

modelJpaRepositoryDb1.save(model);
otherTableJpaRepositoryDb1.save(new OtherTable(model));

modelJpaRepositoryDb2.save(model);
otherTableJpaRepositoryDb2.save(new OtherTable(model));
```

Comment: OK thank you, I'll have a go at this. I must say it seems super complicated for what I would have thought should be a normal functionality. I wonder how would people implement a sort of historical values of data, a sort of log of the previous versions. I don't know.  Anyway, thanks a lot. I'll let you know.